# Speed Improvement of threads Delphi

Tags: multithreading, performance, delphi, delphi-xe2, complexity-theory

My question is regarding types/kinds of application improvements. I would like to improve my thread speed(I can not improve thread's complexity). My question is if instead of integer/longint as parameters to functions I will use byte as type will this change/improve my speed?

Instead of sending arrays, sending pointers to these arrays would this technique improve my speed?

What other tricks can I use to improve my thread's speed(except complexity)

The above code it is a simplification of what I use.

```
Type TArray = array of integer;
Type PArray = ^TArray;

Procedure TMyThread.ProcessFunction(iNr:integer; vArray:PArray);
begin
   vArray^[iNr-2]:=5;
   //......
end;

Procedure TMyThread.Execute;
var vArray:TArray;
    i,iNr:integer;
begin
   Randomize;
   While Not Terminated do
   begin
       iNr:=Random(240);
       SetLength(vArray,iNr);
       for i:=0 to iNr-1 do
          vArray[i]:=i+2

       ProcessFunction(iNr,@Array);
   end;
end;
```

Is there any method to improve this?

Comment: At least explain how you pass "parameters" to threads. Without any examples it makes no sense to reopen

Comment: I see votes to reopen? I don't think we can reopen a post closed by a diamond mod. Am I wrong?

Comment: `TArray` already is a reference. Your code can access the array out of bounds. You need to ask a real question with a concrete and realistic example. Asking about performance in such a nebulous way is pointless.

Comment: Why does everyone think threading is a solution to their issues?

Comment: @NickHodges: I think what someone said about regexp could also apply to threading: **`Some people, when confronted with a problem, think “I know, I'll use threading.”   Now they have two problems.`**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not clear where the alleged performance issue lies since we don't know what ProcessFunction actually does, but one possibility is that performance is killed by the (re)allocation of vArray. If that's the case you can probably speed it up by pre-allocating just one array of 240 that you then pass in along with the actual size you are using on each iteration. And as David Heffernan points out, having an explicit pointer is unnecessary since TArray is already a reference type.